# Python email module ImportError: No module named utils

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, python-requests

My installation of Python's [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library has been working perfectly for months and it has decided to break today.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .request import RequestMethods
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/request.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .filepost import encode_multipart_formdata
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/filepost.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .fields import RequestField
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/fields.py", line 1, in <module>
    import email.utils
ImportError: No module named utils
```

The trouble calling [`utils`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html) is related to the [email](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) module in Python 2.7

```
>>> import email
>>> import email.utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named utils
```

`utils` is clearly a part of Python's `email` library, but it can't be accessed.  If I uninstall and reinstall:

```
$ sudo pip install email

Collecting email
  Downloading email-4.0.2.tar.gz (1.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.2MB 286kB/s 
Installing collected packages: email
  Running setup.py install for email
Successfully installed email-4.0.2
```

**Worst of all `utils.py` is actually present.  What am I doing wrong?**

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/email/
base64mime.py   errors.py       header.py      message.py      parser.pyc
base64mime.pyc  errors.pyc      header.pyc     message.pyc     quoprimime.py
charset.py      feedparser.py   __init__.py    mime            quoprimime.pyc
charset.pyc     feedparser.pyc  __init__.pyc   _parseaddr.py   test
encoders.py     generator.py    iterators.py   _parseaddr.pyc  utils.py
encoders.pyc    generator.pyc   iterators.pyc  parser.py       utils.pyc
```

Comment: Do you have an `email.py` module of your own in the module search path that might be shadowing the one from the standard library?

Comment: YES i just noticed it!!  **head hurts**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing a library from (or near) a script with the same name raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or an ImportError or NameError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-a-library-from-or-near-a-script-with-the-same-name-raises-attribute)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Most likely one of your own modules in the module search path (including the current working directory) is actually called `email`. This will cause Python to pick up that module instead, and it will shadow the `email` module from the standard library, leading to that import error.

Rename that module to something else, and you should be good.

Comment: Yeap, happened to me too, I didn't have an `email.py` file, but the folder I had my email module in was called `email` and that wrecked things up.

Comment: also, if you had named your script something like `email.py` and tried to run it and got these errors, after renaming it make sure you remove any `email.pyc` files and/or `__pycache__` directories

Comment: Had a script called `email.py` Changed it to `email-test.py` and the imports in the script worked. Also cleared the .pyc file in `__pycache__`. Great answer! Thanks!