# Getting error `No module named mime.text` [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, sendmail

This code is "suppose" to send an email.

```
import smtplib
#SERVER = "localhost"

FROM = 'myEmail@email.com'

TO = ["toEmail@email.com"] # must be a list

SUBJECT = "Hello!"

TEXT = "This message was sent with Python's smtplib."

# Prepare actual message

message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail

server = smtplib.SMTP('myserver')
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myCpu\Documents\myFiles\python\test wy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "C:/Users/myCpu/Documents/myFiles/python\email.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mime.text
```

---

Using:

Python 2.7

Windows 7 Professionnal

Gmail (@gmail.com)

---

**Can anyone help me with this code?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rename the file you are working on named email.py to something else. It is likely breaking imports in your libraries.

Comment: This is what i get:`server = smtplib.SMTP('myserver')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`

Answer (score 19):

This is what I did for gmail.
Hope this sloves your problem

```
 from email.mime.text import MIMEText

    def construct_mesage():
      message = MIMEText(message_text)
      message['to'] = to
      message['from'] = sender
      message['subject'] = subject
      return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

Comment: Do I simply run this?? or is something else needed??

Comment: This give you a raw object you can this to sever

Comment: I get this now: `No module named utils`

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874326/python-email-module-importerror-no-module-named-utils

Comment: last thing... `global name 'base64' is not defined`

Comment: "import base64"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127415/discussion-between-januka-samaranyake-and-dat-ha).

Comment: check messagess

Comment: I also got the same issue in Python 3.8. So that my solution is:    from email.mime.text import MIMEText